# converting date string to int

Tags: c, date, integer, scanf, c-strings

I want to convert a date string to int.

```
char date1[20], date2[20];
    
int day1, month1, year1, day2, month2, year2;
    
printf("Enter the first date in the format dd-mm-yyyy: ");
scanf("%s", date1);
    
printf("Enter the second date in the format dd-mm-yyyy: ");
scanf("%s", date2);
```

Then I want to store the corresponding values in day1, month1, year1, day2, month2, year2 int variables. Input is taken in string format as (dd-mm-yyyy) format. I need to extract dd from string and store in day1, mm from string and store in month1 and extract yyyy from string and store in year1. Same follows for 2nd date that is date2. How do I do it?

Requesting help!!

Comment: `date[0] * 10 + date[1] - '0' * 11` would give you the day, month and year analogously...

Comment: You might, though, want to consider invalid input, i.e. before doing above calculation you might test the respective digit positions with `isdigit` function and explicitly check the separators for indeed being a hyphen – and possibly string length as well. Even more important: you might want to prevent the user writing beyond array bounds (undefined behaviour!) such as `scanf("%19s", date)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

u can use ptr

```
char *ptr = date1;
char day1_c[10] = {0x00,};
char month1_c[10] = {0x00,};
char year1_c[10] = {0x00,};

strncpy(day1, ptr, 2);
strncpy(month1, ptr+3, 2);
strncpy(year1, ptr+6, 4);

int day1 = atoi(day1_c);
int mont1 = atoi(month1_c);
int year1 = atoi(year1_c);
```

Comment: It would be much simpler to replace the hyphens within the date by 0 characters and then parse from the original array directly. No need for intermediate arrays that are far to large anyway...

Comment: Actually you don't need the `ptr` variable either – you can just as easily copy from `date1`, `date1 + 3` and `date1 + 6` directly. As soon as you apply arithmetic operators on an array it decays to a pointer automatically, just as occurred when you did the assignment.

Comment: @DHEERAJ SWAROOP S M  The provided code is invalid and can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: 낑낑깡, `strncpy(year1, ptr+6, 4);` is a problem if `ptr` points to string with length less than 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example standard C function `sscanf`. Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char date[] = "21-02-2023";

    int day, month, year;

    if (sscanf( date, "%d-%d-%d", &day, &month, &year ) == 3)
    {
        printf( "day = %d, month = %d, year = %d\n", day, month, year );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Error:invalid date" );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
day = 21, month = 2, year = 2023
```

However before using `sscanf` you should check that the string denoting a data has the correct format that is for example that year contains exactly four digits and the delimiter is the character `'-'`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int valid_date_format( const char *date )
{
    int valid = 1;

    while (isblank( ( unsigned char )*date )) ++date;

    // check day
    valid = isdigit( ( unsigned char )*date++ ) && isdigit( ( unsigned char )*date++ );

    valid = valid && *date++ == '-';

    // check month
    valid = valid && isdigit( ( unsigned char )*date++ ) && isdigit( ( unsigned char )*date++ );

    valid = valid && *date++ == '-';

    // check year
    valid = valid && isdigit( ( unsigned char )*date++ ) && isdigit( ( unsigned char )*date++ ) &&
        isdigit( ( unsigned char )*date++ ) && isdigit( ( unsigned char )*date++ );

    if (valid)
    {
        while (isblank( ( unsigned char )*date )) ++date;
    }

    return valid && *date == '\0';
}

int main( void )
{
    char date1[] = "21-02-2023";

    int day, month, year;

    if ( valid_date_format( date1 ) && sscanf( date1, "%d-%d-%d", &day, &month, &year ) == 3)
    {
        printf( "day = %d, month = %d, year = %d\n", day, month, year );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Error:invalid date" );
    }

    char date2[] = "21-02-2023A";

    if (valid_date_format( date2 ) && sscanf( date2, "%d-%d-%d", &day, &month, &year ) == 3)
    {
        printf( "day = %d, month = %d, year = %d\n", day, month, year );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Error:invalid date" );
    }
```

The program output is

```
day = 21, month = 2, year = 2023
Error:invalid date
```

Comment: Curious, why `isblank()` and not `isspace()` as used in `strtol()` and friends?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica How can its call of scanf  store for example the new line character in a string?:) I think it will be enough to check spaces and tab characters.

Comment: OP's `scanf("%s", date1);` does not save a `'\n'`, `' '`, or any white-space.  That makes `while (isblank( ( unsigned char )*date )) ++date;` unnecessary for OP.  Yet, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The function is general. It deals with strings. It knows nothing about scanf. For example he could use scanf( "%19[^\n]", date1 );  But I preferred  to use isblank instead of isspace.